3D wireframes processing
I have two wireframes, one is what is called a "isoshell" in geostatistics, basically the union of outside faces of cubes, and the other a smooth version of it.

Here you can see in blue the smoothed wireframes and in gray the "isoshell", does anybody know any python package or algorithm that I can implement in order to efficiently smoothout the "isoshell" points and make them look more like the smoothed wireframe?.
